# Spring hateoas: add the exact value on the link

Tags: spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I want to return a self reference for any object I return in list, so I do:

```
for(PetModel pet : pets){
            pet.add(linkTo(methodOn(PetController.class).getPetById(pet.getId())).withSelfRel());
}
```

This gives me:

```
{
"links": [
  {
    "rel": "self",
    "href": "http://localhost:8080/pet/{petId}"
  }
],
"id": 1,
```

wouldn't it be possible to get instead http://localhost:8080/pet/1?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.slash(pet.getId())`

```
Link link = ControllerLinkBuilder
                .linkTo(PetController.class)
                .slash(pet.getId())
                .withSelfRel();

//Add link to singular resource
pet.add(link);
```

Explanation:

- the `linkTo()` method inspects the PetController class and obtains its root mapping
- the `slash()` method adds the petId value as the path variable of the link
- finally, the `withSelfMethod()` qualifies the relation as a self-link

The `methodOn()` obtains the method mapping by making dummy invocation of the target method on the proxy controller. `methodOn()` is way to get method mapping  not a mandatory part.

Comment: But this way I am not referencing to the method

Comment: you need to set reference of method for list of `PetModel`

Comment: with the explicit api?

Comment: If you are sending list then on list self  link set the method  reference.

Comment: could you please provide an update with the example?

Comment: Can't find where methodOn() is used

Comment: methodOn() is way to get method mapping not a mandatory part. please add more details like controller response service so that I can help you

Comment: Rather knowing your method mapping and controller class mapping how can I help you. Thats why I just add exaplanation so that you can do what you want